# Undefined method colspan in Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have correct code, but Prawn complains to it:

```
class MyClass < Prawn::Document
  # ....
  def def123      
    table main_table , width: bounds.width 
  end

  def main_table
    [[ 
      "0","1", "2", "3", "4"
    ]] + 
    [
      [{content: "data1", colspan: 4}, "111"],
      [{content: "data2", colspan: 4}, "222"],
      [{content:"data3", colspan: 4}, "333"]
    ]
  end
end
```

by saying:

```
undefined method  colspan=  for Prawn::Table::Cell::Text:0x007fb86c3e7020
```

Note that I need to use `width: bounds.width` to be able to make the table fill a whole page.

**prawn (0.12.0)**

Comment: And Prawn version is...?

Comment: @zrl3dx prawn (0.12.0)

Comment: As somebody stated in answer below, try using the latest version, if I remember correctly that function was added later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend updating your Gem file to pull prawn directly from the git repository. Most `undefined method` errors are the result of using an out of date version:

`gem 'prawn', :git => "https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git"`